# How and why to send a MultiPartEntity (best chunked) with OKHttp?

Tags: android, multithreading, http, okhttp

i know it's better to use OKHttp based on HttpUrlConnection, but i dont know why.

Why is it better to use OKHttp instead of the implemented HTTPUrlConnection?

And.. How is it possible to send mixed data. POST Vars and Files. Best would be if there are MultiThreaded possible.

Here's an example of my Client using HttpUrlConnection. How would it look like in OKHTTP?

Dataclass and DataPackage are just modals for holding Files and Data for sending.

The Client if self will be called with a FactoryManager (LazyLoading) by using

```
public static DefaultHttpPostClient getEnterpriseHttpManager() {
    if (defaultHttpPostClient == null) {
        defaultHttpPostClient = new DefaultHttpPostClient();
    }
    return defaultHttpPostClient;
}
```

The Constructor of my HttpClient request it's settings everytime when called.

```
  public static HttpConnectionSettings getDefaultHttpConnectionSettings() throws MalformedURLException {
    HttpConnectionSettings httpConnectionSettings = new HttpConnectionSettings();
    httpConnectionSettings.setPost(true);
    httpConnectionSettings.setMultiThreaded(true);
    httpConnectionSettings.setUrl(new URL(MYURL);
    return httpConnectionSettings;
}

   public HttpResult executeRequest() {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    HttpResult httpResult = new HttpResult();
    try {
        connection = Mfactory.getOkHttpClient().open(httpConnectionSettings.getUrl());

        connection.setConnectTimeout(300000);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod((httpConnectionSettings.isPost()) ? "POST" : "GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        connection.setReadTimeout(300000);
        connection.setDefaultUseCaches(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        if (httpConnectionSettings.isPost()) {
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, boundary=XXXXXXXXXXYY");
        }

        out = connection.getOutputStream();

        MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();

        for (Object aMData : dataClass.getData().entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry mapEntry = (Map.Entry) aMData;
            String keyValue = (String) mapEntry.getKey();
            String value = (String) mapEntry.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new StringPart(keyValue, value));
            } else {
                Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "Value was null for key " + keyValue);
            }
        }


        for (DataPackage dataPackage : dataClass.getDataPackages()) {

            if (dataPackage.getbFile() != null) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new BytePart("upfile", dataPackage.getbFile(), dataPackage.getfName()));
            } else if (!dataPackage.getsFile().equals("")) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new FilePart(new File(dataPackage.getsFile()), dataPackage.getfName(), dataPackage.getMimetype()));
            } else if (dataPackage.getmFile() != null) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new FilePart(dataPackage.getmFile(), dataPackage.getfName(), dataPackage.getMimetype()));
            }
            if (dataPackage.getMimetype() != null) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new StringPart("mime", dataPackage.getMimetype()));
            }
            if (dataPackage.getFilesize() != 0) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new StringPart("filesize_orig", String.valueOf(dataPackage.getFilesize())));
            }
            if (dataPackage.getFilepath() != null) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new StringPart("filepath_orig", dataPackage.getFilepath()));
            }
            if (dataPackage.getfName() != null) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new StringPart("filename_orig", dataPackage.getfName()));
            }
            if (dataPackage.getLastmodified() != 0) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new StringPart("lastmodified_orig", String.valueOf(dataPackage.getLastmodified())));
            }
            if (dataPackage.getAdded() != 0) {
                multipartEntity.addPart(new StringPart("added_orig", String.valueOf(dataPackage.getAdded())));
            }
        }
        multipartEntity.writeTo(out);


        if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            Log.e("httpResult", "Response: " + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage() + " content:" + connection.getURL());
            httpResult.setSuccess(false);
        } else {
            Log.d("httpResult", "Response: " + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + connection.getResponseMessage() + " content:" + connection.getURL());
            httpResult.setSuccess(true);
            httpResult.setInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            for (DataPackage dataPackage : dataClass.getDataPackages()) {
                if (dataPackage.isDeleteAfter()) {
                    new File(dataPackage.getFilepath()).delete();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (out != null) {
            try {
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return httpResult;
    }
}
```

Does it make sense switiching to OKHttp? I've lots of requests. Sometimes there are about 100 Threads open (Each Thread with an Executor is it's own HttpRequest).

Why should i use OKHttp? Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do in your situation is to use `OkUrlFactory` from the okhttp-urlconnection module. Then you can use OkHttp 2 without the hassle of changing too much.

You'll need to switch to OHttp's new API if you want to let OkHttp take care of dispatching requests. But there's no obligation to do this in your situation.